# How to let myprogram.py use venv without setting any envs beforehand?

Tags: python, python-venv

I'm a newbie to python(3), but not to programming in general.

I'd like to distribute a git repo with myprogram consisting of these files:

```
requirements.txt
myprogram.py
lib/modulea.py
lib/moduleb.py
```

My question is: What is the best-practice and least surprising way to let users run  `myprogram.py` using the dependencies in `requirements.txt`? So that after `git clone`, and some idiomatic installation command(s), `./myprogram.py` or `/some/path/to/myprogram.py` "just works" without having to first set magical `venv` or `python3` environment variables?

I want to be able to run it using the `#!` shebang so that `/path/to/myprogram.py` and double-clicking it from the file manager GUI does the correct thing.

I already know I can create a `wrapper.sh` or make a clever shebang line. But I'm looking for the best-practice approach, since I'm new to python.

### More details

I'm guessing that users would

```bash
git clone $url workdir
cd workdir
python3 -m venv .
./bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

And from now on this uses the modules from `requirements.txt`:

```bash
./myprogram.py
```

If I knew that the project directory was always `/home/peter/workdir`, I could start the `myprogram.py` with:

```
#!/home/peter/workdir/bin/python3
```

but I'd like to avoid hard-coding the project directory in `myprogram.py`.

This also seems to work in my tiny demo, but clearly this is brittle and *not* best-practice, but it illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib', 'python3.10', 'site-packages'))
```

I'm sure I could come up with some home-grown shebang line that works, but what is the idiomatic way to do this in python3?

Again: After `pip install`, I absolutely refuse to have to to set *any* environment variables or call any setup code in future shells before running `myprogram.py`. (Unless that *strongly* conflicts with "idiomatic", which I hope isn't the case)...

Comment: After the virtual environment is created and populated (dependencies from `requirements.txt` installed), the program can be started as `path/to/venv/bin/python path/to/myprogram.py`. No need to activate the virtual environment. No need to set environment variables. No need to mess around with `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but I want to be able to run it with the shebang (or double click it from the file manager) and have it run correctly. I'll update the question, as this is unclear apparently.

Comment: Maybe try a "[zipapp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html)"-based distribution package, such as [pex](https://pypi.org/project/pex/) or [shiv](https://pypi.org/project/shiv/).

Comment: The other best approach would be to transform your `myprogram.py` into a real _pip_-installable project with an "entry point". This way at install-time pip would also automatically create an executable wrapper for that entry point. Steps would be `git clone project && cd project && python -m venv . && ./bin/pip install . && ./bin/myprogram`. Where `./bin/myprogram` has the correct shebang so that it can be called from anywhere.

Comment: @sinroc. That is probably the exact proper way to do this. How is that done? I'll try https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/ ?

Comment: Yes, that is a good tutorial and up-to-date.

Comment: If you'd care to turn that into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Feel free to write the answer and accept it, once you have the whole setup working. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding @sinoroc's comment into an answer:

I've looked at https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/ and also at "entrypoints", and this is the smallest example I can think of. Create an empty directory with these two files:

**`pyproject.toml`**:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "example_module_pmorch"
version = "0.0.1"

[project.scripts]
runme = "example_module_pmorch:cli_main"
```

**`src/example_module_pmorch/__init__.py`**:

```ini
def cli_main():
    print("I'm the entrypoint")
```

Now if I run this:

```bash
$ python3 -m venv .

# Adding -e during development is optional 
$ ./bin/pip install .
```

Then `./bin/runme` does the right thing and prints `I'm the entrypoint`.

Comment: Perfect. Now you might also consider moving the content of `requirements.txt` to a `dependencies` list under the  `[project]` secttion of `pyproject.toml`. See [here](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/dependency/) for example (since you picked `hatchling` as build back-end, but it should be the same with other back-ends anyway, except Poetry as of today).

Answer (score 0):

I do not see why you would need to hardcode anything. From your last snippet it looks like you are forcing the Python import system to include the *target directory* of the virtual environment you first create.

Based on your explanation, it seems you are using [venv](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/venv.html) as your virtual environment manager. So long as your users install the dependencies in the virtual environment, and then activate the virtual environment before running the script, the dependencies will be ready for your module/script to use them.

This line you share: `./bin/pip install -r requirements.txt` manually uses the package manager of the virtual environment you create with `python3 -m venv .`. Instead, you would want your user to create the environment (`python3 -m venv example-env`), activate the environment (`source example-env/bin/activate`) and then run the pip install command: `python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`.

The user of the package has to make sure that the environment is active before running the script.

Comment: "The user of the package has to make sure that the environment is active before running the script."

This is exactly what I **don't** want. I don't want anybody to have to source anything (which basically just sets up environment variables). I want to use the virtual environment directly when `myprogram.py` is run.